# import a export default typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

I try to use the [numbro](https://github.com/foretagsplatsen/numbro) js library using typescript. 
Their numbro.d.ts export stuffs like that

```
declare const numbro: NumbroStatic;
export default numbro;
```

So I tried a very simple import

```
import numbro from 'numbro'; 
var string = numbro(1000).format('0,0');
console.log(string);
```

From the typescript part, that seem ok, I can tsc my file without error. 
JS generated code is

```
"use strict";
var numbro_1 = require('numbro');
var string = numbro_1["default"](1000).format('0,0');
console.log(string);
```

Now, if I try to execute this code, I have this error :

```
numbro_1.default is not a function
```

If I change the js manually to

```
numbro_1(1000).format('0,0');
```

it works.
Did I missed something? It is a problem in their js export or that come from my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import * as numbro from 'numbro';
```

Comment: Give me this error : "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature". According to the default exports section of this page, I'm not suppose to used "*" -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Their file `numbro.d.ts` seems to be wrong. Maybe they use SystemJS [which add a `default` member](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5285).

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
import numbro = require("numbro");
```

See also this answer: [What does "... resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415661/why-cant-i-import-a-class-or-function-with-import-as-x-from-y) for why you should do this

Comment: give me same error on the line I try to use it "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature." on line "numbro(1000).format('0,0');"