# How can I import a third-party function into typescript class?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to import deepEqual function (https://github.com/substack/node-deep-equal) into a Angular class written in TypeScript.

I've installed @types/deep-equal and I have set module in tsconfig.json to es2015.

`import * as deepEqual from 'deep-equal';`
is not working: *[ts] Module '"node_modules/@types/deep-equal/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.*

`import 'deep-equal';` also not working: *[ts] Cannot find name 'deepEqual'.*

If I manually add the definition at top of the page, the app compiles but throws an error at runtime (not surprisingly): *An error occurred ReferenceError: deepEqual is not defined*

This is the export from js file: `var deepEqual = module.exports = function (actual, expected, opts) {...}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415662/426422

Comment: @MikeCheel tried it, but this only works if I change module to commonjs which I prefer not to do

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/350.