# Type definitions: Create instance of module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using the excellent [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) library in my Typescript-based application. Cleave.js is used as follows:

```
import * as Cleave from 'cleave.js';

new Cleave(element).[whatever]
```

To aid in development, I'm developing typings for Cleave.js, however, I can't find an pattern in Typescript that allows me to specify the above construct.

When I use `export class Cleave { ...}  export default Cleave;`

In the case above Typescript complains:

```
TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

When I import Cleave as `import Cleave from 'cleave.js'` typescript attempts to find the `default` field on the imported object which obviously does not exist.

**How can write typings for new-able modules?**

Comment: You cannot import a class using `* as`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415662/1704166

Answer (score 2):

This does not work. The `import * as X from 'y'` syntax creates a module namespace object. It is meant to be not callable.

You should use the syntax: `import Cleave = require('cleave.js')` instead.

For learning how to write typings, check out http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates.html and related sections in the handbook.

Comment: And how should I write the typings, which is my ultimate question?

Comment: Updated with link to that :)