# Import .json files into Angular - "resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct."

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to import a .json file into a typescript file in angular.

```
import * as languagesData from './../../data/languages.json';
```

The above import statement gives the following error:

> untouchable-app/library/data/languages"' resolves to a non-module
>   entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

Folder structure.

```
library/
projects/
node_modules/
tsconfig.json
typings.d.ts
```

I have updated to typescript version `2.9.2`

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "library": [
        "library/"
      ],
      "library/*": [
        "library/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**library/services/report/report.service.ts**

```
import * as languagesData from './../../data/languages.json';
```

**projects/project-name/src/app/app.component.ts**

```
import { ReportService } from 'library/services/report/report.service';
```

**Note**

I have a "library" folder which contains common components and services that can be shared across multiple apps contained in my projects folder. I am importing a service from the library into my application. The service file is the one that contains the import statement to the json data.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415661/what-does-resolves-to-a-non-module-entity-and-cannot-be-imported-using-this

Comment: does it work in your case using the tsconfig?

I have tried, it doesn't work in my project. Do you have any update about this?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding following to your tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     ...
  }
```

And then import your json files this way:

```js
import languagesData from './../../data/languages.json';
```

This worked for me (Angular 6, with angular cli).